# Dynamically adding textbox to span or div with JQ Mobile... refresh?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to dynamically add a textbox to a span or div or whatever.. I'm doing this:

```
 $('#optionsArea').append('<input type="text" class="q1Options" name="q1Options" data-theme="b" value="" />');
```

This works however, the textboxes do not come in as a JQ Mobile style text box... I know that the refresh command is used on most form elements...but have tried it with .text and .textbox and couldnt get it to change.

Can someone tell me how to add these as JQMobile textboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer -- sorry for posting prematurely (I can delete this if it is wished or it might be good to leave it up as its not immediately apparent) --unless you actually read the docs :)

Calling

```
$('input').textinput();
```

does the trick!

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/textinputs/index.html  -- Bottom of this page is where I found it.

Comment: [You did the right thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12513/164403). Don't forget to accept your answer when possible.

Comment: Looks like a good answer, I would post a link to the resource where you found this info.

Comment: This seem to enhance every textbox. What if you want to enhance only one specific textbox?